# What is text in select element

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to find all `OPTION` inside the `SELECT` using following JavaScript code.

```
var temp = document.querySelectorAll("select");
console.log(temp[0].childNodes);
```

and html markup is this

```
 <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
 </select>
```

But it gives me following output in Google Chrome browser

[image]

so what is text in output that apear before every option.

Comment: The "text" nodes seem to be whitespace. [Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/3a2mzqre/).

Comment: @showdev yes you are right but i want options only

Comment: From the docs, The [`Node.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) read-only property returns a live collection of child nodes of the given element. childNodes also includes e.g. text nodes and comments. To skip them, use [`ParentNode.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) instead.

Comment: @RayonDabre can you provide jsfiddle or codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [`Node.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) read-only property returns a live collection of child nodes of the given element. childNodes also includes e.g. text nodes and comments. To skip them, use [`ParentNode.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) instead.[*From the docs*]

```js
var temp = document.querySelectorAll("select");
console.log(temp[0].children);
```

```html
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the `options` property of `select` element,

```
var temp = document.querySelectorAll("select");
console.log(temp[0].options);
```

`childNodes` will give you the empty text nodes(white spaces/returns) also. So it is recommended to use `options`. Other wise you can use `querySelectorAll` over the fetched `select` element.

```
var temp = document.querySelectorAll("select");
console.log(temp[0].querySelectorAll("option"));
```

Comment: It is returning `\n` character.. It is showing the same after `option` as well!

Comment: @RayonDabre Yeah I already _`childNodes will give you the empty text nodes(white spaces/returns) also.`_ explained it. Anyway thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 1):

The text value is what you retrieve for this :

```
 <select id="selectid">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo text</option>  
  <option value="saab">Saab text</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes text</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi text</option>
 </select>
```

now if you want all the `<option>` objects use this:

```
$("#selectid option").each(function()
{
    //you get "each" option for the select in the id.
});
```

using pure javascript

```
 function displayResult() {
var x = document.getElementById("selectid ");
var txt = "All options: ";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    txt = txt + "\n" + x.options[i].text;
}
alert(txt);
 }
```

Comment: it requires jQuery how we can accomplish same in pure javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
var selects = document.querySelectorAll("select");
var firstSelect = selects[0];
var firstSelectOptions = firstSelect.querySelectorAll("select");
// firstSelectOptions[0].innerText
// firstSelectOptions[0].innerText
```

Comment: it will return all option of selects in webpage what if we want option of particular select as i'm doing in question